# Copying SVN from Local

Tags: svn

I have an SVN checked out copy, Now Instead of pulling everything from the Server on my other computer, If i copy the SVN checked out folder on my new machine and run SVN update, Will it work? ie. replicate the same scenario of an svn checkout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes creating a copy of the checked out project acts as another local copy only you can commit and update changes from either location (i.e. assuming you copy all the .svn folders as is)

Comment: Cant i have another user at the other terminal push to the repo, and not me? I suppose like GIT it just makes the user additions in a file stored some place else and not the local pulled copy of the folder.

Comment: Another user can commit from that local repository provided that they have commit access to that repository